# Export firebase real-time database collection to Bigquery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

is any way to Export firebase real-time database collection to bigquery?

firestore-bigquery-export@0.1.13 extension option is available for the firestore database.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in or pre-built extension that I know of to provide a similar export to BigQuery from the Firebase Realtime Database. It sounds like a reasonable feature request though, so I recommend filing it [here](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/issues).

In the meantime, keep in mind that all Firebase Extensions are open-source, so you can take the [code for the `firestore-bigquery-export` extension](https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/next/firestore-bigquery-export) and use that to either create your own extension for RTDB, or otherwise set up an export.